# How to get session in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I have value in Session **UserID**, I want to access this id in a function in global.asax
if session expires i can get it in **void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)** other wise it showing error **Session state is not available in this context**

What to do?

Comment: As value is stored in current session , after ending that session there memory will be destroyed, so you have to save it on somewhere else if you want to access that value even after Session_End Method

Answer (score 5):

Try accessing the value of session in [HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event using [HttpContext.Current.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Some code here
  string strYourKey = HttpContext.Current.Session["YourKey"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: could you please show a sample code... and i want to know how to get this value in my function in global.asax

Comment: The problem is when i closed the browser i didn't get session in my function

Comment: You wont get any server side event when you close browser

Comment: You can detect browser closing in javascript and send ajax request to update session.

Comment: how can i send ajax request to update session ? (I am using Master page)

Comment: This may guide you, http://kalpeshshirodker.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/accessing-session-from-javascript-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net/

Comment: I have a timer in global.asax which checks the user is online in every 30 seconds. If the user is not online i want to delete that userId from from my apllication state.For that i need to get session in my function (in global.asax) called AbortUser.

This is my need..

Comment: Session is kept for user, If you access it in global.asax it would be in session of some user. You should keep track of logged in user in database and on each user start session update database and on logout update database accordingly. Using timer is not right option here

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
    HttpContext.Current.Session != null) {
  var data= HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionvariablename"];
}
```

Link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1661936.aspx

Comment: Sorry...  HttpContext.Current.Session is always null except Session_End

Comment: The problem is when i closed the browser i didn't get session in my function